# (Capybara, Ruby) How do i check the dropdown has more than 1 value (7 values in this case)?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, capybara, rubymine

(New to testautomation) Hopefully someone can help me out. I need to be able to check the dropdown has a specific amount of values (in my case 7 different values) which change every month or so. So I can't hardcode the values that are within this dropdown.

How do I get it to check the dropdown has 7 values, independent of what the actual value is?

For example:

````
<option value="">""</option>
<option value="123456">XZY</option>
<option value="123457">ZYX</option>
<option value="123458">ABC</option>
<option value="123459">CBA</option>
<option value="123460">BAC</option>
<option value="123461">DEF</option>``` 

And next month it would be: 
<option value="">"-"</option>
<option value="123457">ZYX</option>
<option value="123458">ABC</option>
<option value="123459">CBA</option>
<option value="123460">BAC</option>
<option value="123461">DEF</option>
<option value="123462">FED</option>
````

Comment: You want the `count` option that can be passed to expectations, but we need to see some of the surrounding HTML in order to provide a complete answer with necessary scoping

Comment: <select name="selected[randomvalue].playroundNumber" type="text" id="subscription_cancellation_edit_form_selected_randomvalue__playroundNumber" class="form-select"><option value="">""</option>
<option value="123456">XZY</option>
<option value="123457">ZYX</option>
<option value="123458">ABC</option>
<option value="123459">CBA</option>
<option value="123460">BAC</option>
<option value="123461">DEF</option>

Comment: Does this help? Or do I need more html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```rb
within("select.form-select") do
   page.all('option', count: 7)
end
```

Comment: Yes, this worked with a little ID-adjustment. Thanks for the help both of you!

Comment: Glad to hear, if you find this helpful then can you please approve the answer?